# What is the difference between "impossible" and "infeasible"?

Tags: meaning, differences

In cryptography world I usually encounter the word "infeasible", like:

"It is computationally infeasible to solve elliptic curve discrete logarithm."

But I rarely see the word "impossible" being used in cryptography. Is there some actual difference between these two words? I'm not native speaker so forgive me if it is too obvious question.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/infeasible) gives the meaning of infeasible as: *Not possible to do easily or conveniently; impracticable.* So it does not mean 'impossible' but 'difficult' or 'unrealistic'.

Comment: The infeasible we do immediately; the impossible takes longer.

Comment: "Feasible" is part of the folklore of engineering and optimization.  I think that's why.

Comment: The word *impossible* in math has a much stronger meaning than difficult. The word *infeasible* might refer to something that could be feasible with more computing power, or quantum computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impossible) - "impossible":

> An impossible situation is extremely difficult to deal with or solve

This suggests something is *extremely difficult* and will take *a long time* to solve. You could also say it is literally *impossible* to solve and *cannot be solved*.

[Lexico Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/infeasible) - "infeasible":

> Not possible to do easily or conveniently; impracticable

This also means *difficult*/*unrealistic*/*impracticable*